# Is message lost when there's n/w issue while publishing the message to RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using Spring AMQP to publish messages to RabbitMQ. Consider a scenario:
1. Java client sends a message to MQ usin amqpTemplate.convertAndSend()
2. But RabbitMQ is down OR there's some n/w issue

In this case the message will be lost? OR
Is there any way it'll be persisted and will be retried?

I checked the publish-confirm model as well but as I understood, ultimately we've to handle the nack messages through coding on our own.

Comment: We need to handle that.Retry logic should be in our code.You can use publisher confirm to check whether message is published successfully or not.If not then retry from code.

Comment: You can use a `RetryTemplate`, avoiding the need to add retry logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RabbitTemplate` supports adding a `RetryTemplate` which can be configured whit whatever retry semantics you want. It will handle situations when the broker is down.

See [Adding Retry Capabilities](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#template-retry).

You can use a transaction or publisher confirms to ensure rabbit secured the message.